# Inherent error in mass and volume?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

In one of my chem classes I had to do a lab that involved finding the mass and volume of a substance.  I did three trials and for my mass I got 9.3g, 9.3g, and 9.4 g.  For my volume, I got 9.7ml, 9.9ml, and 9.9 ml.

I am being asked to find the inherent instrument error calculation.

For volume, I used a graduate cylinder which has `1 % vol/reading` as an inherent error.

For mass I used a one place electronic balance which has error of `0.1g/reading`

How would I find the error in mass and the percent error in mass?

Answer (score 1):

Is the **percent** error formula you are looking for something like the formula [this](http://www.percenterrorcalculator.com/index.php) website service offers? Your lab instructor should have given you the formula, perhaps you missed that. Do you have a reliable lab partner you can ask? The error in mass would probably be something to do with how far each measurement deviates from the average.

If for example I used a 250 ml Erlenmeyer flask which had marks at only 25ml increments. I would then say that I could make a 'guess' as to what the volume is at if I were trying to measure something less than 25ml or between two marks. But the error for that instrument would then be somewhere around +/- 12.5ml error. My general-chem teacher was fine with that, maybe you should ask yours?

I was told that the convention is to expect at least 2% error in the last significant digit if not explicitly defined. When taking a measurement with a device like a graduated cylinder, you always measure down to the most precise "known" value, and then the last significant digit is your own judgement.